# Need to commit and push my changes to same branch again

Tags: git, github

I am new to Git.I made a change to the branch, I committed and pushed to the remote.Now I need to make another commit & push to the same branch.

So now whether I can simply commit and push to the remote or I need to rebase the initial change with the master first and then commit & push to remote.Kindly help

Comment: You can certainly _try_ to another `git push`.  The worst that can happen is that Git will tell you that you are behind the remote.  In this case, you can either rebase your branch on `master` or merge `master` into it.  After this, the push should be successful.

Comment: what is the correct way to do it tim?

Comment: As I said, you can try just doing another `git push`.  Go on, try it.  If it doesn't go through, then come back here and post another comment.

Comment: push successfull thanks.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen- If i want to make this 2 commits to a single commit.I need to rebase and squash it rite?whether my understanding is correct?

Comment: Yes this sounds right.  But beware, you are rewriting history and if you want to push your local branch you will need to _force_ it.  If anyone else is sharing this branch with you I would advise you to not squash.  However, if you are the only one using the branch then you can try this.

Comment: thank you..i am only using this branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming no one else has pushed to the branch you should just be able to make a new commit and push. If you try to push and someone else has made another commit, like Tim has said, git will tell you can't, so just pull/rebase and then try again.

Comment: If i want to make this 2 commits to a single commit.I need to rebase and squash it rite?whether my understanding is correct?

Comment: To squash commits I'd recommend reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git/5201642#5201642